# How to lambda the group by data on a LINQ to Sql results?

Tags: linq-to-sql, lambda, group-by

1. I get the data from the database like this.

   ```
    Dim query = From t1 In TBL1 _
                Join t2 In TBL2 On t1.ID Equals t2.ID _
                Join t3 In TBL3 On t1.ID Equals t3.ID _
                Group Join t4 In t1 _
                      On t1.ID Equals t4.ID _
                      Into t4_Grp = Group _
                Select t1, t2, t3, t4_Grp
   ```
2. As the user performs a search I am able to filter the query results like this.

   ```
   query = query.Where(Function(o) o.t1.ID = lngID)
   ```
3. All works fine above.  Until I want to lambda the t4_Grp.  I do not know how to do a   lambda expressions on the t4_Grp?

Comment: Could you clarify your question, what do you mean by "do a lambda expression" or "lambda the t4_Grp"? Are you trying to do extra filtering, but on table t4 instead of t1?

Comment: Yes I am trying to do extra filtering; on the t4_Grp.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in the past to do some power-grouping.

```
private void ProducePivotAnalytic <T, K>(IEnumerable<T> colletion, Func<T, K> pivot)
{
    var grouped =
        from n in colletion
            group n by pivot(n) into g
            select new { theKey = g.Key, theValue = g };
    // do some stuff with your grouped collection.
}


ProducePivotAnalytic<List<DateTime>, DayOfWeek>(
        myDates,
            (x) => (x.DayOfWeek) );
```